# Word Co-occurrence - find the co-occurence of a term in a set of n-grams

Tags: lucene, hadoop, nlp, weka

How would I go about writing a co-occurence class in something like Java that takes a file full of n-grams and calculates word co-occurence for a given input term.

Are there any librarys or packages which work with Lucene (indexes) or something like a map-reduce over the n-gram list in Hadoop..?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas... Thinking Solr/Lucene might be best approach for this but not sure how...

Comment: ...sounds dumb but: is it really needed? If the corpus is a few millions of tokens, or the ngrams a few millions, a simple java or python program will do.

Comment: I did something like that once, just perl and mysql and displayed it on a webpage

Comment: @GatoVolador do you have any example?

Comment: Excellent question -- I would have expected more answers -- I always write one-ofs ... perhaps it is time to release some code

Comment: @user1172468 I'd be interested to see an answer! Please share - happy to change the answer

Comment: cool will try to post code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so assuming you want to find the co-occurrence of two different words in a file of ngrams....

Here's pseudo code-ish Java:

```
// Co-occurrence matrix
Hashmap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>> map = new HashMap();

// List of ngrams
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ngrams = ..... // assume we've loaded them into here already

// build the matrix
for(ArrayList<String> ngram:ngrams){
  // Calculate word co-occurrence in ngram for all words
  // result is an map strings-> count
  // words in alphabetical order
  Hashmap<String,<ArrayList<String>,Integer> wordCoocurrence = cooccurrence(ngram) // assume we have this

  // then just join this with original
}

// and just query with words in alphabetic order
```

Doing a count like this would probably be pretty with Pig but you're probably more familiar with that than me